# How to Compare Rows Stored in a Datatable with Multiple Tables' Rows in a Local SQL DB?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, datatable

I have acquired data from my Oracle server and stored it in a DataTable (u). I have verified that the correct data has been acquired and stored.

I also have a local SQL database that has multiple tables, each with a column that carries a unique identifier.

What I would like to be able to do is compare the Oracle data stored in DataTable (u) with these various local SQL database tables, and then show the values(s) within the local SQL database tables that are identical to the values within the Oracle DataTable (u).

How would I perform this comparison while being able to tell what the matches are?

My current unfinished code:

```
    using (OracleDataAdapter b = new OracleDataAdapter(sql2, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();

                OracleCommand cmd2 = new OracleCommand(sql2, conn) { CommandType = CommandType.Text };
                cmd2.BindByName = true;

                cmd2.Parameters.Add(":user_name", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = cboUserName.SelectedValue;

                var u = new DataTable();
                b.Fill(u);


                lstFunctions.DisplayMember = "Function_Name";
                lstFunctions.ValueMember = "Function_Name";
                lstFunctions.DataSource = u;


                SqlConnection sodconnstring = new SqlConnection(@"***\SODGROUPS.sdf");

                sodconnstring.Open();


                SqlCommand sodcommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl1, tbl2", sodconnstring);

                SqlDataAdapter sodAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sodcommand);

                var sodGroupData = new DataTable();
                sodAdapter.Fill(sodGroupData);

                conn.Close();
                sodconnstring.Close();
            }
```

Please let me know if you require any additional input.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you share the schema of the tables (both oracle and SQL), it would be hard to guess a solution.

This line would return the join of tbl1 and tbl2 and I'm sure to compare the values, you would n't need a join .

`SqlCommand sodcommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl1, tbl2", sodconnstring)`

Comment: Thanks. The data column stored in the Oracle DataTable (u) is named "Function_Name". The data which may hold the comparable data in the local SQL DB is of the column "Function". These are unique identifiers in each database. Basically, what I want to do is if the 2 SQL tables contain values stored in the Oracle DataTable u, then show which values are comparable.